# Java MySQL check if value exists in database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to check, if a specific value already exists in my database. I am accessing database from java standalone app using JDBC (queries for inserting records into db work so my setup and connection are ok).

```
String queryCheck = "SELECT * from messages WHERE msgid = " + msgid;
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(queryCheck); // execute the query, and get a java resultset

// if this ID already exists, we quit
if(rs.absolute(1)) {
     conn.close();
     return;
}
```

I am getting this error (there is apparently something wrong with my SQL syntax):

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd-f05708071f8f' at line 1
```

However, if I try to execute this command in my MySQL command line, it works! Can you tell me, whats wrong with my statement? Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Please, please, please, ALWAYS use query binding... ALWAYS not only you prevent SQL injection attacks, you also help the database as it will cache the execution plan making the next query faster.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to wrap a `String` in quotes in MySQL, so the query needs to be

```
SELECT * from messages WHERE msgid = 'd-f05708071f8f';
```

Not

```
SELECT * from messages WHERE msgid = d-f05708071f8f;
```

So the code should read

```
String queryCheck = "SELECT * from messages WHERE msgid = '" + msgid + "'";
```

I would suggest using a `PreparedStatement` to avoid these sorts of issues and any risk of SQL injection:

```
final String queryCheck = "SELECT * from messages WHERE msgid = ?";
final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryCheck);
ps.setString(1, msgid);
final ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
```

Using string concatenation for query building is considered very bad practice. Has been for a long time now.

Further I would suggest using `select count(*)` rather than the full `select *` as this returns much less data (think of the size of the `ResultSet`) and MySQL can optimise it too.

```
final String queryCheck = "SELECT count(*) from messages WHERE msgid = ?";
final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryCheck);
ps.setString(1, msgid);
final ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
if(resultSet.next()) {
    final int count = resultSet.getInt(1);
}
```

Comment: yep, forgot hyphens and I was testing it only with integers... my bad.. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use bind variables.

```
 PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT * from messages WHERE msgid = ?");
 st.setString(1, msgid);
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(queryCheck);
```

Or get into manual quoting, but that is risky.

In addition to preventing SQL injection, prepared statements should also improve performance if you run the same query repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

Since msgid is a varchar you need to surround the value in the where clause with single quotes.

```
String queryCheck = "SELECT * from messages WHERE msgid = '" + msgid + "'";
```

Dynamically generating SQL strings is not recommend however since it can expose your application to sql injection.

Instead use a `PreparedStatement`:

```
            String queryCheck = "SELECT * from messages WHERE msgid = ?";
            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryCheck);
            st.setString(1, msgid);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes arount the parameter:

```
"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msgid = '" + msgid + "'";
```

Or better you use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
String queryCheck = "SELECT * from messages WHERE msgid = '" + msgid + "'";
```

You have missed quotes around msgid. (I'm assuming that **msgid** is `String` and not `Integer` value. )

Comment: Just a suggestion when answering on here, if a user is concatenating Strings to be used for sql queries, always recommend a `PreparedStatement` many users will downvote you instantly if you don't, on the same note you will get some upvotes for mentioning sql injection/preparedstatements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single quotes

```
SELECT * from messages WHERE msgid = 'd-f05708071f8f';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql1 ="SELECT Time FROM monday_wednesday WHERE Time ='"+time.getSelectedItem()+"'";
pst=con.prepareStatement(sql1);
rs=pst.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()) {
    if(rs.getString("Time").equals(time.getSelectedItem())) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Time is already taken","",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
    }
} else {
    String sql="INSERT INTO monday_wednesday(pfname,pmname,plname,Birthdate,Gender,Address,City,Contact,Contactperson,Time,Date)\n" + "VALUES ('"+txtFirstName1.getText()+"','"+txtMiddleName1.getText()+"','"+txtLastName1.getText()+"','"+d+"','"+gender.getSelectedItem()+"','"+ txtAddress.getText()+"','"+txtCity.getText()+"','"+txtContact.getText()+"','"+txtContactPerson1.getText()+"','"+time.getSelectedItem()+"','"+dateFormat.format(date)+"')";
}
```

Just a simple duplicate entry algorithm